# Renaming folder causes included file not to be found

Tags: c++, makefile

I have a LibA/tests/tests.h file with an include as follows:

```
#include "../../LibB/abc.cpp"
```

This file compiles.

I change the name of the "tests" folder to "Integration_Tests", so now my file is LibA/Integration_Tests/tests.h

Now this file does not compile and the message displayed is:

```
fatal error: ../../LibB/abc.cpp: No such file or directory.
```

What could possibly prevent the abc.cpp file from being found ? "Integration_Tests" folder is at the same location as "tests" folder.
So if "abc.cpp" was found when the folder was named "tests", it should also be found when the folder is named "Integration_Tests".

Here is a short version of my tree:

```
~library/LibA/tests/tests.h
~library/LibB/abc.cpp
```

Comment: Relative up-path-traversal in a include is a terrible practice.  It's very brittle and makes it much more difficult to rework directory hierarchies.  As you have discovered.

Comment: Better to tell the compiler where things are, instead of this relative path stuff. In fact, better still to get a build system involved. This should have been a directory rename and a cmake edit; your code should not have needed to be touched for this task.

Comment: Do you need to cmake again?  Your makefile may contain details about files before the folder was renamed.  I assume all you did was `make` to rebuild after the rename, right?  You should list more details about your platform, compiler and toolchain.

Comment: Also: `#include`ing a .cpp file from a .h is at least unusual.

Comment: I agree with all the comments about what an odd and unusual method this is, but to actually answer your question I can't see any reason for this error given the situation you've described to us.  So, it seems likely there is something about the situation that isn't described here, that's causing the problem.

Comment: The original code is not mine, I agree its quite a strange approach. The system is Red Hat 7.6. THe compiler is gcc 9. A Makefile is used but I am not connected to the system just now so cannot give any further details about it at present.

Comment: the reason must be that when you say you rename the folder from `test` to `Integration_Tests` then there is actually more you do or that is happening without you noticing it. Carefully consider the directory structure before and after

Comment: Please share a short version of your tree - so that SO readers will be able to replicate problem and advise a solution.

Comment: Ok, shared above

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find the solution to the above issue.
Finally, I was advised to simply move the file that I was including into my current folder. This solved the immediate problem.

What caused the issue when I renamed the folder is still a mystery, but I don't plan to investigate it any further. I will put it down to some unpleasant consequence of what the posters of comments above said: "Relative up-path-traversal is a terrible practice" and a reminder that it should not be done.

Thank you to all who commented above.